# Using custom headers when piping external image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to pipe images from an Amazon S3 server through my node server while adding a custom header to the response.

Right now, however, the server will respond with a plain "Document" that will download to my computer with no file extension declared. The "Document" still contains the desired image data, but how can I make it clear that this is a PNG that can be viewed in my browser?

Here's my current code:

```
app.get('/skin', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*'});
    http.get("http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/clone1018.png").pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use http.request in order to make nice proxying and resource loading with duplicating headers.
Here is example in express that will listen on port 8080, and will make request to specific server with actually url that you request from /skin/* route:

```
var http    = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    app     = express();

app.get('/skin/*', function(req, res, next) {
  var request = http.request({
    hostname: 's3.amazonaws.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/' + req.params[0],
    method: req.method
  }, function(response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.writeHead(response.statusCode, response.headers);
      response.pipe(res);
    } else {
      res.writeHead(response.statusCode);
      res.end();
    }
  });
  request.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('something went wrong');
    console.log(e);
  })
  request.end();
});

app.listen(8080);
```

In order to test it out, run it on your machine, and then go to: `http://localhost:8080/skin/nyc1940/qn01_GEO.png`
It will load that image proxying from Amazon, and returning its headers as well. You might customize headers as well, in order to prevent XML being sent from S3 (when file does not exist).

You dont need to set any headers as they are proxied from s3.amazon and it does reliably set right headers for you.
Nor `access-control-allow-origin` as you will need it only in case with AJAX request to resource from another domain name. But anyway feel free to modify `response.headers` before sending out. It is simple object (console.log it for tests).

Comment: How would I wrap this in the app.get, if I had a subdirectory being requested like /skin ?

Comment: As well as customizing the headers, how would I put the headers I specified in the question in the `writeHead` ?

Comment: I've updated answer. Please feel free to play with it your self, rather than asking to code for you. Cheers.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try it. I do need the access-control-allow-origin because S3 doesn't have CORS by default.

Comment: But CORS is needed only for browser that is trying to AJAX domain from another domain. While you are querying your own proxy, and if that proxy is on same domain as your website with JS, you don't need any CORS.

Comment: I'm working with a library called voxeljs, and it won't load images from other sites unless they include CORS. The creator said this himself.

Comment: But you are using your own site to serve images now (proxying) so no need in CORS.

Comment: I understand that I can do this without CORS if I'm serving the images to a client accessing the server. But It's a sort of API for other sites to get minecraft skins.

Comment: It goes through your node.js server - this called proxy. Client has no idea about amazon, as it speaks to your server. You server will have traffic hit obviously because of proxying.
So it comes from your server, and your server asks amazon for resources.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was asking this because there was a bug in chrome where images served directly from amazon s3 will not appear in the browser unless embedded, while other sites that serve images directly from amazon s3 are fine. This script had the same bug.

Comment: It depends of the way your script loads files. It can load then as XHR request, and then use loaded blob to create Image. Or it can create `new Image()` and attach `.src` to it. With first option - it would need CORS, with second does not.